# Youtube videos keep buffering. Browser independant

Tags: 16.04, youtube

Suddenly Youtube has stopped working on my computer. To be more precise, the site works fine but the videos never stop loading. This happens across all browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera). Other websites (Twitch in particular) work just fine.

I have tried updating flashplugin-installer and ubuntu-restricted-extras, but it did not change anything. Does anyone have an idea of where it could come from?

Comment: Do you have VLC media player installed?